# Order by some property nulls first?

Tags: java

I have List of some objects. And i want to order by some property and nulls first, such as in query:

```
select * from aaa order by ext_id nulls first;
```

I know when i have list of string i can do this:

```
   List<String> names2 = Arrays.asList("XML", null, "Java", "HTML", "CSS");
    names2.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo));
```

But what when i have List of some objects of class?

Any suggestion how can i achive that in java?

Comment: "But what when i have List of some objects of class?" why do you think it's any different? `Comparator.nullsFirst(YourClass::whateverMethod)`?

Comment: you have to implement your own `Comparator`

Comment: implement `Comparable` in your class and override `compareTo` method. then go the usual way.

Comment: You don't have to implement `Comparable`. You just have to compare comparable things.

Comment: you can do that, for example: `Collections.sort(list,Comparator.nullsFirst( Comparator.comparing( User::getName)));`

Comment: @MedElgarnaoui note that `Collections.sort(List,Comparator)` [delegates to `List.sort(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) anyway, so you may as well use the latter directly, as OP has.

Comment: @MedElgarnaoui im getting ava.lang.NullPointerException: null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        a1.setName("A");
        A a2 = new A();
        a2.setName("B");
        A anull = null;
    List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(a1);
    list.add(a2);
    list.add(anull);
    list.sort(nullsFirst(
            comparing(A::getName, nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))));
    list.forEach(System.out::println);

}

public static class A {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).