# Is there a better way to compare and sort objects in list?

Tags: java

Is there a better way to compare and sort objects in list?

here is example of class and simple comperator

```
class Zadanie{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String type;
    public int priority;
    public Date date;
    public boolean isDone;
}

Collections.sort(zadania, new Comparator<Zadanie>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Zadanie o1, Zadanie o2) {
                                return Integer.valueOf(o2.priority).compareTo(o1.priority);
                            }

                        });
```

Comment: This is good way to do sorting

Comment: Sure, `zadania.sort(Comparators.comparingInt(Zadanie::getPriority));`. You need to implement the getter, (I'm assuming `zadania` is a `List`).

Comment: Agree, this is a good way. There are some cases where better solutions exist, but then we need to consider how you are storing it as well.

Comment: Note: no reason to use `Integer.valueOf` - `Integer` has a `compare` method for comparing `int` (but the `Comparator` solution above is more recommended IMO)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71499755/14756421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sorting lists, prefer `List.sort` for simplicity. When comparing primitives, use the `comparingInt` (or other suitable) method and use it with a method reference of your getter.

You can then sort a list of **any** objects with the same basic format:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(MyClass::getPropertyToSortWith));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, only code can ble slightly shorter using lambdas

```
Collections.sort(zadania,Comparator.comparing(Zadanie::getPriority));
```

or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort your list with `JAVA-8 Stream-API`:

```
List<Zadanie> sortedList = zadanieDtoList.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Zadanie::getName).reversed())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I sort the collection based on a specific variable, which is `Name`!!

Comment: Why do you think this is more efficient than `Collections.sort`?

Comment: @kaya3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49799203/7189597

Comment: That answer you provided states that stream will be slower and gradually difference will be smaller if N gets bigger. So its the other way around. Also banchamrk "above" that answer somehow confirms that

Comment: @kaya3 Yess!! you are right buddy, that's OK, so today was a good day because I learned something new ;-)